# Usage of "red in |- *": What does bar hyphen star mean?

Tags: syntax, coq, coq-tactic

In a lot of Coq code, like in [the definition of sets](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/V8.2pl1/contribs/Algebra.Sets.html#relation) in the standard library, I've seen this sort of notation:

```
 red in |- *.
```

What does the `|-*` (bar-hyphen-star) mean?

My searching hasn't turned up any results, but it's hard to search for punctuation, so please excuse me if this is a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an *occurrence clause* and

> The role of an occurrence clause is to select a set of occurrences of a term in a goal.

I'd add "to which the tactic is going to be applied" to the above quote (The Coq Reference manual, [sect. 8.1.4](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec337)).

Then the manual proceeds with the following:

> if `*` is mentioned on the right of `|-`, the occurrences of the conclusion of the goal have to be selected.

Let's look at some simple cases:

- `<tactic> in * |-.` applies `<tactic>` to every hypothesis, but not to the current goal.
- `<tactic> in H1, H2 |- *.` applies `<tactic>` only to the hypotheses `H1` and `H2` *and* the goal.
- `<tactic> in * |- *.` applies `<tactic>` everywhere. There is also a shortcut for this case: `<tactic> in *`.

For many tactics `<tactic> in |- *.` is equivalent to just `<tactic>`. If, for example, you delete all the occurrences of `in |- *` from the linked file it will still compile.

Comment: That's really convenient notation! Thank you!